# UIImageView gets resides on retina 4"

Tags: ios, uikit, interface-builder

I've designed layout for controller in IB, but UIImageView gets resized on Retina 4, height is increased. Here's how it looks(Retina 3.5 and Retina 4).

[image]

[image]

As you can see image view overlaps other views on Retina 4. How do I make the size consistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably related to your autoresizing mask in IB.

Be sure you don't allow height to be autoresized. Here's how it should look in the size inspector in IB:
[image]

Any other resizing you want can be done here as well (you might not want it to stretch horizontally either, or whatever).

Alternatively, you can remove 'Autoresize subviews' via the attributes of this image view's parent view.

EDIT:
Ignore the frame (obviously), this is from my own project ;)